# Table Join Across Main Query and Subquery

Tags: mysql

My database contains the following tables:

```
TABLE SALESCOUNT
-----------------------------------
| id | startWeek  | repID | sales |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | FY13M01W01 | 0001  |   4   |
| 2  | FY13M01W01 | 0002  |   8   |
| 3  | FY13M01W02 | 0001  |   5   |
| 4  | FY13M01W02 | 0002  |   9   |
...

TABLE SALES
----------------------------------------------------
| id | salesRepID | salesDate  | division  | team  |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   0001     | 2013-01-01 |   divA    | teamA |
| 2  |   0002     | 2013-01-01 |   divC    | teamA |
| 3  |   0001     | 2013-01-01 |   divD    | teamD |
| 4  |   0002     | 2013-01-08 |   divB    | teamC |
...

TABLE DEPT
-------------------------------
| id | repID | region | dept  |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 0001  |   01   |   A   |
| 2  | 0002  |   02   |   B   |
| 3  | 0001  |   C    |   A   |
| 4  | 0002  |   02   |   B   |
...

TABLE GEO
-----------------------------------
| id | geo   | regionA | regionB  |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | geoA  |   01    |     A    |
| 2  | geoA  |   02    |     B    |
| 3  | geoB  |   03    |     C    |
| 4  | geoB  |   04    |     D    |
...

TABLE FISCALWEEK
--------------------------------
| id | salesDate  | startWeek  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 2013-01-01 | FY13M01W01 |
| 2  | 2013-01-08 | FY13M01W02 |
...
```

The following query returns the desired results:

```
SELECT y.startWeek, SUM(y.sales), dept.dept, geo.geo
FROM salesCount as y,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.salesRepID
    FROM sales AS a
    WHERE (a.team IN ("teamA", "teamB", "teamC)
        AND a.saleDate BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-06-30"
        AND a.division IN ("divA", "divB", "divC")
) as x
INNER JOIN dept
    ON x.salesRepID = dept.repID
INNER JOIN geo
    ON dept.region = geo.regionA OR dept.region = geo.regionB
WHERE x.salesRepID = y.repID
    AND y.startWeek BETWEEN "FY13M01W01" AND "FY13M06W04"
GROUP BY y.startWeek, geo.geo, dept.dept
ORDER BY y.startWeek ASC, geo.geo ASC, dept.dept ASC
```

My goal is to utilize the FISCALWEEK table to generate the 2 date pairs (1 in the WHERE clause of the subquery and 1 in the WHERE clause of the main query). I would like to be able to enter the date pair as (xxxx-xx-xx) in a single place and use that to populate both areas with the date in the required format. Unfortunately, I am not able to alter the data or tables.

I have been searching for quite a while and can't seem to find an answer that I am able to transfer to my situation. I have tried numerous permutations with this being the only one I can come up with that gives me the desired results. Please let me know if you have any questions or need any additional information. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, are you looking for an UPDATE query that updates the `SALES.salesDate`  and `FISCALWEEK.salesDate` at the same time?

Comment: You can create a subquery with just one registry with the date you want and use it to join with your query. Something like `(select date_format('2013-01-08','%Y-%m-%d')) as dtvalue`

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head, maybe you could start by extracting the saleDate into the outer query:

```
SELECT y.startWeek, SUM(y.sales), dept.dept, geo.geo
FROM salesCount as y,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.salesRepID, a.saleDate
    FROM sales AS a
    WHERE (a.team IN ("teamA", "teamB", "teamC)
        AND a.division IN ("divA", "divB", "divC")
) as x
INNER JOIN dept
    ON x.salesRepID = dept.repID
INNER JOIN geo
    ON dept.region = geo.regionA OR dept.region = geo.regionB
WHERE x.salesRepID = y.repID
    AND y.startWeek BETWEEN "FY13M01W01" AND "FY13M06W04"
    AND x.saleDate BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-06-30"
GROUP BY y.startWeek, geo.geo, dept.dept
ORDER BY y.startWeek ASC, geo.geo ASC, dept.dept ASC
```

Then from there you can look at joining the FISCALWEEK table, something like:

```
SELECT y.startWeek, SUM(y.sales), dept.dept, geo.geo
FROM salesCount as y,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.salesRepID, a.saleDate
    FROM sales AS a
    WHERE (a.team IN ("teamA", "teamB", "teamC)
        AND a.division IN ("divA", "divB", "divC")
) as x
INNER JOIN dept
    ON x.salesRepID = dept.repID
INNER JOIN geo
    ON dept.region = geo.regionA OR dept.region = geo.regionB
INNER JOIN fiscalweek
    ON y.startWeek = fiscalweek.startWeek
WHERE x.salesRepID = y.repID
    AND y.startWeek BETWEEN "FY13M01W01" AND "FY13M06W04"
    AND x.saleDate = fiscalweek.salesDate 
GROUP BY y.startWeek, geo.geo, dept.dept
ORDER BY y.startWeek ASC, geo.geo ASC, dept.dept ASC
```

Not sure if this will work but hopefully gives you some ideas